# Find the largest prime factor of the number 60085147514 (project euler #3)

Tags: python, primes, factors

I have to find the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143.
The answer is 6857 but I keep getting 486847. What is the bug in my code?

```
def f(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n))+1): #check if it is a factor
        if n%i == 0:
            x = True
            for j in range(1, int(math.sqrt(i))+1): #check if factor is prime
                if i%j == 0:
                    x = False
                x = True
            if x:
                factors.append(i)
    return max(factors)

print(f(600851475143))
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging code.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it

```
import math

def f(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n))+1): #check if it is a factor
        if n%i == 0:
            x = True
            for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1): #check if factor is prime
                if i%j == 0:
                    x = False
                    break
                x = True
            if x:
                factors.append(i)
    return max(factors)

print(f(600851475143))
```

two issues

1. for checking primality start from 2, as 1 will divide everything
2. break after you have set `x` as false otherwise you will set it true again and keep appending everything to the list

Comment: Alternatively for #2, you can be more judicious about how `x` is set by removing the second `x=True`. In fact, you should remove it anyway, because that line is not needed.

Comment: just fixing the issue i saw , instead of  suggesting new approach

Comment: I'm suggesting an additional fix, not a new approach.

Comment: @MingPokNg i am glad

Comment: @MingPokNg please consider accepting / upvoting the answer if it solves your problem